# os.path.getsize() returns negative filesize for large files (for > 3GB file size)

Tags: python, linux

I am using python on embedded device which is running linux 2.6.32.

Using python to fetch the file size as `os.path.getsize()` returns me a negative value.

I refered to one of the [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167120/why-does-os-path-getsize-return-a-negative-number-for-a-10gb-file) here on stack overflow and tried recompiling python with `CFLAGS='-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' OPT="-g -O2 $CFLAGS"`
 but still it returns negative file size.

I am using python 2.6.4 with Django 1.2.4 on linux 2.6.32.

Can any one tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Reading that question, I think the Linux kernel needs to support large files as well; if it's an embedded device, it might not be compiled to support large files.

Comment: but "ls -lh" shows correct file size..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, something is wrong with your Linux distribution's build of Python. Rather than fix the actual problem, it might be easier to just work around it:

```
def getsize_workaround( filename ):
    size = os.path.getsize( filename )
    if size < 0:
        import subprocess as s
        size = long( s.Popen("ls -l %s | cut -d ' ' -f5" % filename,
                    shell=True, stdout=s.PIPE).communicate()[0] )
    return size
```

Comment: Nice idea, but what if the file is between 4 and 6GB in size? Presumably the code would get (and return) a positive number that's wrong?

Comment: Ah, good point. The 32-bit rollover could occur more than once. It'd be more reliable to just ditch the conditional and always use the 'ls -l' wrapper.